# How to make jQuery fire event less frequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have an input field where the user types info, something like the following:

```
$('input').on("keyup", function(){
    // make an ajax call
});
```

I want the call made less frequently. How should I do it? I tried `setTimeout` and `delay()`. Couldn't achieve what I want. Can someone help?

Comment: whats your actual need?

Comment: You could put a delay function inside the keyup function, but what are you trying to do with this?  Are you trying to block all user input for x seconds in a field?  Do you want to cache the keypress and process it later?

Comment: I want wait till user finish their input, say they are inputting a word, instead of making call for every single letter they add, I want make a call util they input a whole word.

Comment: Would it be better to detect word limiters from the entered value instead of a certain delay?

Comment: @Teemu one use case would be user input a long code without space or other limiter in between. Hence make call less frequently would be a universal solution

Comment: debouncing or throttling are both options for controlling how often a callback executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var timer = $(this).data('__timer');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).data('__timer', setTimeout(function(e){
        //Your ajax here.
        console.log(e)
    }.bind(this, e), 500));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer to delay the AJAX call until a certain amount of time has passes since the last `keyup`:

```
  $('input').keyup(function() {
      // delay the search unless 0.5 seconds have passed since last keyup
      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
      $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(<AJAX function call>, 500));
  });
```